# how to apply xlMarkerStyles to a Chart Plot in Excel vba without directly using the xlMarkerStyleAutomatic

Tags: vba, excel

I have a x,y scatter chart with lines connecting the dots from one source. I have between 1 and 8 lines and I need to have the MarkerStyle assigned to each line. Since the lines are not fixed and depend on the current data, I can't say which lines are there.

In general I could just assign

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleAutomatic
```

But that also assigns unwanted/unreadable Markers. So could I create a Collection with the Markerstyles I want and than assign that?

I tested

```
Dim colMarker As Collection

Set colMarker = New Collection

colMarker.Add "xlMarkerStyleCircle"
colMarker.Add "xlMarkerStyleSquare"
colMarker.Add "xlMarkerStyleTriangle"

With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)

    .MarkerStyle = colMarker(1)

End With
```

But the error msg is `wrong type`

What type do I need?

Thanks Kaz

Comment: Do you have multiple series in the chart? Or is it just one series?

Comment: I guess I reveal my ignorance here :-D I add another series of dots which are connected with the same line with `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` and I call them with `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)`

Is that a series than? I have about 10 of those :-P

Comment: You are adding String literals to your collection by the way. You need to remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the marker style for each series individually:

```
Dim s as Series

s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
s.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
```

Edit:

To assign different marker styles use the approach you suggested, but when adding styles to the collection it should be done like this:

```
colMarker.Add xlMarkerStyleDiamond
```

etc, ie without quotation marks.

Comment: My problem was just solved by your answer with the String literals. If you give that as an answer, I can mark it.

And this answer, is this way any different from

    ActiveChart.FullseriesCollection(i).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle

Where i is the current Series? It is just that I can keep better track of the Series, right?

Comment: You can use the FullSeriesCollection(i) too. I initially thought you were having trouble getting a handle on the different series, but seems the problem was in getting the different marker styles into the collection.

Comment: Yes, I just did not think about the quotation marks ... could have been so easy. Do you want to give the answer?

Comment: I just found another option to add styles like this: `s.MarkerStyle = 1`

0 seems to be the automatic value

Comment: Yes, the markerstyles are an enumeration, meaning they are all actually just numbers. xlMarkerStyleSquare = 1, xlMarkerStyleDiamond = 2, xlMarkerStyleCircle = 8, and so on.